# Bode plot? H(s)= 1 / (s² +1)

Tags: control, bode-plot

I have transfer function  $$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

When I put that in Wolfram Alpha I get that there is peak on Bode plot at 1 and it is 60dB. Why? There is no damping here...

Usually in formula there is equation that that damping peak is calculated 40*log(damping value)?

Also why is phase bode plot like this? I mean with lets say straight lines.

Comment: Tony, what was that edit all about. It looks as cranky as Cranky McCrankface

Comment: Mobiles may not convert Mathjax in Titles or comments. I just copied body into title.  Who is she ? Mc$$

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 related to [Boaty McBoatface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaty_McBoatface).

Answer (score 1):

> There is no damping here

No there isn’t because you don’t have an unsquared ‘s’ term in the denominator. As the formula currently stands there will be an infinite peak in the response at w = 1 (despite wolfram limiting it to 60 dB).

A conventional low pass filter will have this type of transfer function: -

$$\dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_ns +\omega_n^2}$$

Where zeta is the damping ratio and, if zeta is zero you lose the unsquared s term.

Comment: I know it is infinite peak. How do you mean unsquared?

Comment: no 1st order s parameter

Comment: I know, there is no damping parameter at all. But why it goes to infinite than?

Comment: It is artificial yet ζ=0

Comment: If you convert s to jw in order to inspect the bode plot, s squared becomes -w^2 and, when w = 1, the denominator becomes zero and the TF becomes infinity.

Comment: Aha straight lines on the phase plot. That’s what you get with zero damping ratio, the phase changes instantly 180 degrees at the singularity of resonance.

Comment: @Kiry There is no damping because the poles of your transfer function are purely imaginary at +/- j . The real part of the pole create the damping.